# Copy link of an anchor tag to clipboard when clicking on it

Tags: jquery

This is the code that I have used to show some of the data. In this code, I am having anchor tag and I want to copy the link of that anchor tag when clicking on it. This is the code I have used as below:

```
<div class="search_item_list clearfix" id="response">
   <?php foreach($jobs as $job){
   ?>
    <a class="copy_text"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy to Clipboard" 
       href="<?=base_url().'home/company_profile_detail?id='.$job['company_id'];?>"><span class="icon link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>Copy Link</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<script>
   $(".copy_text").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var button = $(this);
      var text = button.attr("href");
      text.select();
      $(document).execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text ");
   })
</script>
```

I am getting the jQuery as

> text.select is not a function.

Comment: You just need to call text not text.select()

Comment: if i do that the error would be $(...).execCommand is not a function

Comment: why you use this `text.select();`

Comment: Because to copy the text first you need to select that text
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard

i followed the example from this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try below code snippet

```js
$('.copy_text').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var copyText = $(this).attr('href');

   document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
      e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copyText);
      e.preventDefault();
   }, true);

   document.execCommand('copy');  
   console.log('copied text : ', copyText);
   alert('copied text: ' + copyText); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <a class="copy_text"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy to Clipboard" href="home/company_profile_detail">Copy Link</a>
```

Comment: this is not actually coping the link, meaning the copy to clipboard functionality is not performed by this code

Comment: added code to copy to clipboard. Thanks @ArunSharma

Comment: If you want to copy the absolute URL, use `var copyText = $(this).prop('href');`

Answer (score 0):

Copying value to clipboard via javascript is a bit complicated process. Basically, you have to create fake Input element and use it for `execCommand('copy')`. You can take a look at how it works in this module: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$(".copy_text").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $temp = $("<input>");
                    $("body").append($temp);
                    $temp.val($(this).attr('href')).select();
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    $temp.remove();
                    alert("Copied the text ");
            })
```

In this code, you are creating an `input`, set it's `value` to your `anchor`'s `href`, copy it's `value` to `clipboard` and then `remove` that `input`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v9g1x0o6/   Please visit this for copy text.

```
var succeed;
try {
      succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
} catch(e) {
    succeed = false;
}
```

In this case you have to first select attribute of href of the anchor text and then use 
document.execCommand("copy");