# How to hide TD row but select value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want the row name to be selected without the use of a button. So I made an anchor to call on JavaScript to select the TD value of the row before. This works fine only I now have a duplicate of the rows. So i want the row that the scripts selects from hidden but usable for the script to select its value from.

I tried to apply CSS style="display: none;" to the td tag, it will make the td column disappear but it wont select the $row[name] value but the CSS code I put in the TD tag.

So my question. How do I select the value in the name to clipboard when I need a close td to select from, but I don't want to display the td it selects from? Is this the right way to accomplish this or are there better ways? I now use a found script that uses jQuery.

```
 <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="online btn-copy" style="color:<?= htmlspecialchars($cat_color) ?> !important " onMouseover="ddrivetip('Click to copy the account name!')" onMouseout="hideddrivetip()" >
  <?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?></a></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.btn-copy').on('click', function(){
  element = $(this).closest('td').prev('td')[0];
  var selection = window.getSelection();        
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(element);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  //Losely basd on http://stackoverflow.com/a/40734974/7668911
    try {
       var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      if(successful) {
        $('.res').html("Coppied");
      }
       else
       { $('.res').html("Unable to copy!");} 
   } catch (err) {
      $('.res').html(err);
   }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery. Please tag it accordingly.

Comment: FYI, you _should_ be using a button. Anchors are not for triggering actions. They're for navigation.

Comment: Ok. I just need the text selected to clipboard without the use of a button but by clicking the name it should sellect the name. I could not find anything on the web on how to do it. This was my creative solution to accomplish it..

Comment: Why exactly do you need another element with the same text? Try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53369306/3174790 (of course you would use `$(this).text()` instead of `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: I dont. I need the text to be copyd to clipboard. What i use now with jquery and all other examples are designed with a button. So i tried rewriting that to make it select the text on click and its searches for the closes td so therefor i needed a colomn before the name one so i made a duplicate. An example what does just copy the text would be better but i cant find it